# Extract string without special characters in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to extract 'gmail' from stack@gmail.com.

I am trying to use

```
select substr(email,(instr(email,'@')+1),(instr(email,'.')-1) from email
```

but output coming is

```
gmail.com
```

Comment: read up on regular expressions

Comment: Please check the description of [`SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E) arguments, return each expression as a separate column and perform substring by yourself treating each argument as it is described in the function definition. The third argument is `length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `SUBSTR` is not start- and end-positions it is `SUBSTR(string, start_position, substring_length)`:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(email, at_pos, tld_pos - at_pos) AS result
FROM   (
  SELECT email,
         INSTR(email,'@')+1 AS at_pos,
         INSTR(email,'.',-1) AS tld_pos
  FROM   email
);
```

or:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
         email,
         INSTR(email,'@')+1,
         INSTR(email,'.',-1) - INSTR(email,'@') - 1
       ) AS result
FROM   email;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE email (email) AS
SELECT 'someone@example.com' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| example |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i5rvl0i3)

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually trying to fetch substring between the *monkey* and the dot that follows, how about line #3?

```
SQL> with email (email) as
  2    (select 'stack.overflow@gmail.com' from dual)
  3  select ltrim(regexp_substr(email, '@\w+'), '@') result
  4  from email;

RESUL
-----
gmail

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function such as

```
WITH t(col) AS
(
 SELECT 'stack@gmail.com' FROM dual
)  
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '(.*@)(.*)\..*','\2')
  FROM t
```

where **`\`** is used as an escape character within **`\.`** in order to distinguish this ordinary dot character from a special dot character (single **`.`**), and the function splits the expression into two pieces from which the second one is picked.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0CgczVZD)</kbd>